# How to consume a Promise from a service (native script / firebase)?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, promise, nativescript

I have a `userService` that calls `firebase.login()` which returns a result of type `Promise<User>`. It is called like this:

```
firebase.login( { config... 
})
.then (function (result) { /* use result */}, 
       function (error)  { /* use error */ });
```

Elsewhere in the project, in a UI component, I need to react to the outcome of the login (i.e. success or error). I do not want to put any routing or similar logic into the user service, but rather have the other component control what happens next.

How is that done? How can another component react to it?

The component mentioned above is a class called `LoginPage`. It has a `Login` button which should start the Firebase login. The button is linked to a function (also called `login()`) in the `LoginPage` class.

XML:

```
<Button [text]="Sign in" class="submit-button" (tap)="login()"></Button>
```

login.component.ts

```
login() {
   this._userService.login(this.user)
   .then(function (data) {
      /* go to next screen */
    });
}
```

The above is obviously wrong, as the `then` clause will always be executed, regardless of the success or failure of the login.

Here is the login function in the `userService`:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {


  login(user: User) {

    firebase.login({
      type: firebase.LoginType.PASSWORD,
      email: user.email,
      password: user.password
    })
    .then( function (result) {
       console.log("Successful Login! " + JSON.stringify(result));
       return result;
     }, function (error) {
       console.log(error);
       return error; 
    });
 }
```

Comment: The second piece of code is Angular 2, not AngularJS. `http` request is RxJS observable, not a promise! You can improve the question by specifying the code for 'login button that calls a login() function' and other related code.

Comment: I am aware that this is different (I stated as much in my question, even without the nomenclature.). Could you perhaps try to answer the question? I do not think the link between button and controller's `login()` function is of any significance. I need to know how to consume the service in that function.

Comment: The question cannot get a quality answer in its current form, it is not clear what your case is. What is 'that function'? Please, specify the relevant code in the question and let the respondents decide if it is significant or not.

Comment: Please specify what is not clear. I have the firebase.login() function and need to be informed of the result in another component. How would you do this if the question were put in these terms? Thanks. (PS: I simplified the question.)

Comment: How *exactly* it is being called? What *exactly* is 'this component'? Because the answer would be 'you need to do something to be informed of the result, depending on your code'. I'm sorry, but you don't make the task easier for SO experts by being vague on the details. I guess that's the reason why the question was voted as *unclear what you're asking*.

Comment: I have added more code which I know is wrong. IMHO it just makes the question longer without adding any value. Do you have enough information now?

Comment: I would recommend using Redux to manage the state of your application. The flow is something like this: login page is subscribed to your application store > user logs in successfully > you update data in application store > you dispatch that the store has changed > login page is updated. A quick google search returned this article https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/angular-2-introduction-to-redux-1cf18af27e6e#.qo30pmmat

Comment: Thanks, this is what should be done in the first place. It wasn't possible to give a quality answer before and it is possible now. It always adds value when relevant pieces of code are posted (adding source code for the entire app doesn't, on the contrary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UserService` `login` method should return a promise to make it available for chaining:

```
  login(user: User) {
    return firebase.login(...)...
  }
```

In the original above login error was already caught, this leaves the promise with resolution that can be either a result or an error.

The preferable way to handle errors here is to not catch the error in the service itself. We always want to know if login request was successful or not.

```
  login(user: User) {

    return firebase.login(...)
    // second callback is optional if we don't need to log errors
    .then( function (result) { ... }, function (error) {
       console.log(error);
       return firebase.Promise.reject(error); 
    });
  }
```

This way an error can (and also should, Angular 2 will throw an error if there are uncaught promises) be caught and handled:

```
login() {
   return this._userService.login(this.user)
   .then(function (data) {
      /* go to next screen */
   })
   .catch(function (error) { ... });
}
```

It is always preferable to return promises, at least for testing purposes.

Comment: That is the solution. I found the same via the appropriate nativescript Slack channel. Well done! :) Looks like I have been right, though, that the mechanism linking the button to the function is completely irrelevant. -- Also, maybe you should add `return firebase.Promise.fulfill(result);` to the first callback? (the other code I found has `return JSON.stringify(result);`.

Comment: It should be `return result` as in your original code, so I omitted it to emphasize the differences. `Promise.resolve` (there's no `Promise.fulfill`) is implied when the result is returned in `then` callback.